# malloc error when reading file in iOS

Tags: objective-c, c, file, char, malloc

i have this function that reads a line from a file character by character and inserts it into a NSString.
RANDOMNLY the system crashes with this error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1e1f6a00: incorrect checksum for freed
object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

function:

```
NSDictionary *readLineAsNSString(FILE *f,int pospass,
                                 BOOL testata, int dimensioneriga)
{    
    char *strRet = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZ);
    int size = BUFSIZ;

    BOOL finito=NO;
    int pos = 0;
    int c;
    fseek(f,pospass,SEEK_SET);

    do{ // read one line
        c = fgetc(f);

        //Array expansion
        if (pos >= size-1) {
            size=size+BUFSIZ;
            strRet = (char *)realloc(strRet, size);
        }

        if(c != EOF) {
            strRet[pos] = c;
            pos=pos+1;
        }
        if(c == EOF) {
            finito=YES;
        }

    } while(c != EOF && c != '\n');

    if (pos!=0) {
        for (int i = pos; i<=strlen(strRet)-1; i++) //size al posto di pos
        {
            strRet[i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    NSString *stringa;
    if (pos!=0) {
        stringa=[NSString stringWithCString:strRet encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    } else {
        stringa=@"";
    }

    long long sizerecord;
    if (pos!=0) {
        sizerecord=   (long long) [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sizeof(char)*(pos)] longLongValue];
    } else {
        sizerecord=0;
    }
    pos = pospass + pos;

    NSDictionary *risultatoc = @{st_risultatofunzione: stringa,
                                 st_criterio: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pos],
                                 st_finito: [NSNumber numberWithBool:finito],
                                 st_size: [NSNumber numberWithLongLong: sizerecord]
                                 };

    //free
    free(strRet);
    return risultatoc;
}
```

where "finito" is a flag, "pos" is the position in the file line,"pospass" is the position in the entire file, "c" is the character, "strRet" is the line and BUFSIZ is 1024.
Each file has n line with the same lenght (for file).

Thanks!!!

Comment: `char *strRet = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZ);` should be `char *strRet = malloc(BUFSIZ);`.

Comment: @H2CO3 - your statement is true for C, false for C++, is that correct that objective-c does not require a typecast as well? I've read that: `"Objective-C syntax is a superset of GNU C/C++ syntax"`

Comment: @Mike That's wrong, Objective-C is a strict superset of C. And thus when talking about Objective-C, **no one ever** cares about the deficiencies of C++.

Comment: @Mike [Something good to read.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
if (pos!=0) {
    for (int i = pos; i<=strlen(strRet)-1; i++) //size al posto di pos
    {
        strRet[i] = ' ';
    }
}
```

is broken. `strlen` just reads until it finds a `\0` ... since you didn't put one in, it can just keep reading off the end of your buffer.

You already *have* `size`, so just use that, or better still just terminate `strRet` instead of right-filling with spaces:

```
strRet[pos] = '\0';
```